Cypress - How to iterate through the values of an environment variable and verify each item from the carousel list
I want to test whether the carousel on my website contains the correct items that are represented as company logos. Each carousel item has an <img> element with the 'alt' attribute which is where the name of the company is stored.
I have set an environment variable in the cypress.env.json file, which is represented something like this:
"companyPartners": {     
    "title": "Company Partners",     
    "partners": {         
        "google": "Google",         
        "facebook": "Facebook",         
        "instagram": "Instagram",         
        "linkedin": "LinkedIn"     
    } 
} 

The carousel elements are represented in an unordered list, something like this:
<ul class="carousel-partners ...">
    <li>
        <a class="carousel-item">
            <img alt="Google" src="...">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="carousel-item">
            <img alt="Facebook" src="...">
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>

So, I want to iterate through each carousel item and verify that the values from the environment variable match the 'alt' attribute of the carousel items.
While running this command in Cypress, I am getting an error which says that only the first letter is retrieved:
Cypress.Commands.add("verifyPartners", () => {
    const companyPartners = Cypress.env("companyPartners").partners
    let text = ""
    for(const x in companyPartners){
        text += companyPartners[x]
    }

    cy.get('*[class^="carousel-partners"]').find("li").each(($listItem, index) => {
        cy.wrap($listItem).find("img").should("have.attr", "alt", text[index])
    })
});


assert expected <img.h-12.w-auto.object-contain.saturate-0> to have attribute alt with the value G, but the value was Google

Is there any way I can verify the items? Any help would be appreciated.

Hello! It seems that in your case there is a problem with parsing the env variable as a json object. I would say that in general Cypress Environment Variables are more intended for strings, rather than objects.
I would suggest using fixtures instead. It also is more consistent with how DDT should be performed - data sets stored separately in a dedicated folder.
I also generally suggest keeping env variables in a config file, rather than in a json file.

I'm going to assume there is one-to-one equivalence between the list and the DOM elements.
To do this

convert partners object to array of RHS values with Object.values()
use within() to narrow the scope of queries
check each partner name is in the DOM on an <img> inside an <li>
then check there's no surplus <img> tags

const partners = Cypress.env("companyPartners").partners

/* 
  take value part of key/value in partners object
  yields ['Google','Facebook',...]
*/
const companies = Object.values(partners)

cy.get('ul.carousel-partners').within(() => {
  // queries here only apply to the contents of the <ul>

  // Two questions:

  // 1) Does every partner exist in the DOM on an li[alt] attribute?
  companies.forEach((company) => {
    cy.get(`li img[alt="${company}"]`)   // passes if exists
  })

  // 2) Does every DOM <li> have a value in the partners list?
  cy.get('li img').each(($img) => {
    const alt = $img.attr('alt')
    expect(alt).to.be.oneOf(companies)
  })

})
  


Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it. I used the first part of the code and resolved the issue. I managed to verify the 'alt' value with the values from the variable. Have a great day!
companies.forEach((company) => {
cy.get(li img[alt="${company}"])   // passes if exists
})
